# Can anyone help me with php-iban library?

Tags: php

I found this library on GitHub I think is pretty awesome for my needs. So I am trying to get the bank name and the country name from the IBAN like this

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST["addBtn"])) {
   $ibanNumber = $_POST["IBAN-NUMBER"];
   $country_name = iban_country_get_country_name($ibanNumber);
   $bankName = iban_country_get_central_bank_name($ibanNumber);
   echo $bankName . " " . $country_name;
}
?>
```

This never returns any info or error. Is there anyone using this library to help me out? https://github.com/globalcitizen/php-iban

Thank you for your replies

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> $country_name = iban_country_get_country_name($ibanNumber);
> ```

If you check the examples under [IBAN Country-Level Functions](https://github.com/globalcitizen/php-iban#iban-country-level-functions), you’ll notice that all of them use a parameter named `$iban_country` - not `$iban`, as the previously listed basic IBAN validation functions. From that, you should be able to deduce, that these methods probably do *not* want the mere IBAN as a parameter, but some sort of IBAN Country value / object.

And if you scroll a bit further down to https://github.com/globalcitizen/php-iban#parsing-functions, you’ll find

```
# Get the country part from an IBAN
$iban_country = iban_get_country_part($iban);
```

So you need to call that first, to extract the IBAN Country from your IBAN - and then you can feed that IBAN Country to `iban_country_get_country_name`.